# Replace Compile in visual studio isolated shell

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm developing an application based on VS isolated shell.

I'd like to know how (and with which steps) is possible to customize building process.
I mean: when the user clicks on **Build**, I want to trigger my just created logic.

Do you know how to create custom *builder* and how to link it to Build action?

Thanks!

Comment: Lookup msbuild targets.

Comment: @user2674389: thanks, but...could you explain me better? :)

Comment: You can add to your project file a target, that will execute before or after build. In this target you can execute programs, log messages, or execute custom generated build tasks that are referenced by assembly.

Comment: @user2674389 Great. This custom generated build task have to implement a specific interface? Do you know any documentation that could help me  through this?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by deriving a class from Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task or implement  Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. The most important is that you need to implement bool Execute() method. Meanwhile, the project file need to be changed so that the task can be invoked (assembly name and class name which implements ITask should be specified):

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   <UsingTask AssemblyFile="SimpleTasks.dll" TaskName="SimpleTask.SetEnvironmentVariable" />

   <PropertyGroup>
      <OutputPath>c:\temp</OutputPath>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <Target Name="MyTarget">
      <SetEnvironmentVariable Name="OutputPath" value="$(OutputPath)" />
   </Target>
</Project>
```

More details see:

http://tech.pro/tutorial/934/creating-msbuild-tasks-in-csharp
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/01/21/515834.aspx